# How to upload multiple data in codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am trying to upload multiple data at once through codeigniter. Please check below code. I tried with few codes on controller but its all went on vain. It is not working at all.

Please help me write code in controller and i am trying to insert using insert_batch code provided by codeigniter and also while storing and uploading image to database and folder i want to change the name so that it will be unique and won't get match with any other images.

Looking forward to help. Thank you in advance. :)

```
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="text" name="user[0][name]" value="">
    <input type="text" name="user[0][title]" value="">
    <input type="file" name="user[0][img]" value="">
    <input type="text" name="user[1][name]" value="">
    <input type="text" name="user[1][title]" value="">
    <input type="file" name="user[1][img]" value="">
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: So you have this working for just a single file?

Comment: yes, i want to upload all these data from single file.